# Use Create Trigger to create New table using calculated values from common groupid column values

Tags: mysql

I have a TABLE_A in Database1 the contains rows with a common group id. I am wanting to use the CREATE TRIGGER function to generate a new TABLE_B in the same Database1 that contains calculated values (summed/multipled ect.) of certain columns with the same group id. and to group these all together. Using Mysql 5.5

ie:

[image]

TALBE_B (New Table Updated as TABLE_A data changes) (using CREATE TRIGGER..? )

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Let's see the `UPDATE` statement you would use if you had to do it manually.  Then modify that into a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` that will take care of either inserting or updating, and let's see that.

Comment: Why in the result 'id' for Mike is 2 ? Also is the TABLE_B structure (DDL) already created and we are just supposed to INSERT values in TABLE_B. OR you want to SELECT, CREATE and INSERT all together ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use MySQL `CREATE TABLE AS` statement to create a TABLE_B from existing TABLE_A by copying the existing table's columns

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_B AS   
SELECT  id, name, SUM(cost) AS 'cost', organization
     FROM TABLE_A            
     GROUP BY name, organization;
```

In MySQL, we cannot have after INSERT or UPDATE description together, like in Oracle unfortunately. So you have to create two TRIGGERs

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER update_tableb
 AFTER INSERT 
  ON TABLE_A FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN

   -- variable declarations

   -- trigger code

    END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you MySQLRockstar. Will this not simply create a table with current data from TABLE_A? I don't believe data would be refreshed to TABLE_B as it changes in TABLE_A

Comment: You are right, in that case we need to create `TRIGGER` with `AFTER UPDATE/INSERT`